# How to count the number of defined value differences between two columns of DataFrame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, difference

Assuming that I have a pandas `DataFrame` defined below:

```
    a     b
0  N/A    3
1   1     1
2   2     0
3   2    N/A
4   0     1
5  N/A   N/A
```

I would like to figure out how many rows with defined values in both columns `a` and `b` have values that are not equal. In this example there are two such rows, with indices 2 and 4. Indices 0, 3 and 5 contain undefined values in at least one of the columns and the row with index 1 has the values equal.

The approach I was thinking about would be to drop all the rows that contain undefined values in either `a` or `b` and then to f.e. take the difference between the two columns and count the number of zeros.

Comment: Can youi explain more? Do you want check value `0` in all columns and return rows? Or something else? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with 2 masks :

```
df1 = df[(df['a'].isnull() == df['b'].isnull()) & (df['a'] != df['b'])]
print (df1)
     a    b
2  2.0  0.0
4  0.0  1.0
```

Detail:

```
print ((df['a'].isnull() == df['b'].isnull()))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool

print ((df['a'] != df['b']))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool

print ((df['a'].isnull() == df['b'].isnull()) & (df['a'] != df['b']))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

General solution working with multiple columns - first check if all Trues are not `NaN`s per rows by [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and chain for compare `DataFrame` by first column by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and return at least one `True` per row by [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df1 = df[df.notnull().all(axis=1) & df.ne(df.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).any(axis=1)]
print (df1)
     a    b
2  2.0  0.0
4  0.0  1.0
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.notnull())
       a      b
0  False   True
1   True   True
2   True   True
3   True  False
4   True   True

print (df.notnull().all(axis=1))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool

print (df.ne(df.iloc[:, 0], axis=0))
       a      b
0   True   True
1  False  False
2  False   True
3  False   True
4  False   True

print (df.ne(df.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Another solution:

```
df = df[(df['a'].notnull()) & (df['b'].notnull()) & (df['a'] != df['b'])]
print (df)
     a    b
2  2.0  0.0
4  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I don't want to have cases where both columns are N/A.

Comment: df[(df['a'].isnull() == False) & (df['b'].isnull() == False) & (df['a'] != df['b'])] ?

Comment: Or `df[(df['a'].notnull()) & (df['b'].notnull()) & (df['a'] != df['b'])] ` is cleaner...

Answer (score 2):

This is one way using [`pd.DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and [`pd.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html).

```
count = len(df.dropna().query('a != b'))  # 2

res = df.dropna().query('a != b')

print(res)

     a    b
2  2.0  0.0
4  0.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

With logical comparison you have a built in way to do that and without wasting resources to sum columns.

Assuming:

```
>> import numpy as np
>> import pandas as pd     
>> d = { 'a': [np.NaN, 1 , 2 , 2 , 0], 'b': [3, 1, 0 , np.NaN, 1]}
>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Easiest way might be:

```
>> df.dropna().a != df.dropna().b

    1    False
    2     True
    4     True
    dtype: bool
```

You can obviously extend the same thing to more columns.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) like this:

```
df.dropna().apply(lambda x: x.a != x.b, axis=1)
```

Just drop all NaN values and then compare the two columns element-wise.

The result is

```
1    False
2    True
4    True
```